# How to use blue press and peel transfer foil for PCB etching?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I decided to try etching my own PCBs and I got some blue press and peel transfer foil. It has shiny and matte side. I'm supposed to print on one side and iron the other, but the procedure of transferring isn't too clear to me and the only site which Google provides appears to be infested with malware, so I'm asking here for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You transfer the image onto the dull side, place that in contact with the copper, and iron on the other side placing a plain sheet of paper between the iron and the P&P stuff. [Here](http://www.eidusa.com/Theory_PnP.htm) is a non-hacked web page.

Members of the [Homebrew PCB Yahoo group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/Homebrew_PCBs/) have found that shiny magazine paper works just as well as that expensive Press and Peel material, and costs nothing, just use sheets from an old magazine. I've tried both, and can confirm that. Moreover, you don't have to worry about which side is which! :) I get much better results using transparencies printed on an inkjet printer with the conventional photo-etch process using precoated positive resist boards.

Comment: That's very good to know, but right now I can't obtain any cheap shiny magazine paper and I have a stock of expensive press and peel which I'd like to use. Also, any specifics on the paper type? I'd guess over 200 $\frac{g}{m^2}$ and shiny, but specific type would be good.

Comment: Everything you need to know about making PCBs is available from the Homebrew PCB group.

Comment: OK. Just for those who can't search for it, the link appears to be http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/Homebrew_PCBs/

Comment: You don't have to run the whole sheet of PnP through the printer if you're doing a small board.  I had good luck printing the artwork on plain paper, then cutting out a rectangle of the right size, and taping it onto the paper over the artwork along the top edge.  Then I ran the sheet again to print onto the PnP.